# How Much Detail Should "Answer your own question" Questions Contain?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, self-answer

I just posted a wiki-style "Answer your own question" question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396788/which-is-faster-select-by-id-or-select-by-index).  It was almost immediately down-voted, and the first commenter told me what I already suspected - that the down-vote was probably because I didn't provide any details about what I had already tried, or any indication that I was putting in any effort at all; two things that are usually baselines for successful questions.

I can see how someone interested in keeping the site on track would see my question and make those assumptions (after-all, self-answers aren't all that common, and are easy to miss), but at the same time I'm not sure how much "I tried this" to add to the question when I tried something and got a concrete result right off the bat.

So, **in cases where you'd like to answer your own question, how much information should you include?**  I feel like giving too much detail can risk convoluting or narrowing what are otherwise often the most abstract, and widely applicable questions.

Comment: As much as any other question.

Comment: @BoltClock but in this case wouldn't that just mean including my answer in the original question?

Comment: That's something I've wondered about as well. Some users suggest fabricating an unsuccessful attempt - but that assumes that it is even possible to do so. I'm not entirely sure that suggestion would apply in your specific case.

Comment: @SandyGifford At the end of the day you should be working to construct a question that you would want to see if you saw someone else post it.  You wouldn't want someone to see a question someone else posted that was answered in the question, nor would you want to see a question that was clearly not at all researched, no effort was put into asking it, etc.  Finding the right balance is most certainly hard.  it's why I discourage people from posting self-answered questions in general (so few are able to get it right).

Comment: @BoltClock right, I totally understand what you're getting at, but in this case I feel I have a pretty concise and useful question that just happens to have a one-step answer.  Faking failed tests just feels like busy work that makes the answer more about "here's what you did wrong" rather than "here's an actual answer to the question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include just as much detail as would be expected of any question that you're *not* answering.  The question will be held to exactly the same standards regardless of whether you're answering it or not.  Likewise, the answer will be held to the same standards regardless of whether its a question you asked or not.

This is of course what makes creating self-answered content hard; many people struggle to create a quality question when they already know the answer, and end up creating low quality questions as placeholders for a place to put an answer.

Comment: In this case, though, the question is fairly straight forward, and just easy to answer.   Question - "which is faster, thing A or thing B"; answer - "I ran a test and found thing A was faster".  Should I include the JSPerf I used for my test in the question *and* answer?

Comment: @SandyGifford: Do you fully describe the scenario you want to compare? Even so, for most cases I'm not sure how to make that a good and interesting question...  there are exceptions though, like http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809, which need lots of work (and for best effect a really good answer).

Comment: @SandyGifford To me that simply makes it a low quality question in general.  I've yet to see a quality question of the form, "which is faster, thing A or thing B?"  Anytime I ever see a question of that form the only realistic answer to it is, "well, run them both and find out; it'll depend on your specific context," which is of course the answer that you gave, "it depends" is just not all that useful of an answer.

Comment: @Servy Well, before I even created the test-case, I spent a good half hour on Google and was genuinely surprised that no one had already answered the question.  The question applies to a basic operation in Backbone.js (and vicariously Javascript), so I figured I'd save the next person a trip to JSPerf.  I guess including my attempts to find an answer online may have added to the question?

Comment: I think he's saying that the question shouldn't even have to be asked on Stack Overflow to begin with.

Comment: @SandyGifford Again, I've yet to see any quality question of the form, "what is faster, thing A or thing B?"  The answer to that question *every single time* is "try both and find out, it'll depend on the specific context."  That's just not a useful question.

Comment: @BoltClock Fair enough

Comment: @Servy sorry to keep dragging you back into this question (I'm going to pick your answer, I'm just waiting for the time limit to be up) but the answer was more concrete.  "Option A" *was* consistently better regardless of context.

Comment: @SandyGifford `On Chrome and at least one of the versions of Firefox I tested, the difference is negligible`  Not according to your answer.

Comment: @Servy A consistent 2:1 performance ratio on one browser more than justifies using one approach over another, even if the difference is less pronounced on other platforms.  If you have an option, and your user-base is even partially in that spectrum, it's a must.  Still, I do accept your answer, and realize that self-answers are difficult and can't be made exceptions for.

Comment: @SandyGifford And what about all of the browsers that you didn't test?  What about all of the different contexts that the method can be used in besides the one that you used (and didn't even specify in the question)?  After all, the specific HTML used, and the element(s) that you're querying are highly relevant to their performance.  It would be effectively impossible to actually cover every single possible context.  You just picked tiny fraction of them.

Comment: @Servy Ah, I see.  Okay, that does make sense.  I do feel that I designed a use-case that is abstract enough to fit all cases, but to be totally honest I think I'd have trouble explaining exactly why in words.  I guess a good question would have included exactly that sort of language.  I'll try and bring that thought to my next question.  Thanks for all the time on this one!