# Is it OK to make a Q&A of a thing that I've already answered elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, support, self-answer

I had filed a post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170827191247/http://www.progtown.com/topic1087358-how-to-compare-two-guid.html) where my answer is the one identified by user srgloureiro.

Is it OK to make a Q&A of a thing that I've already answered elsewhere?

Comment: You mean to ask and answer you own question to add a potentially "useful" solution to the community here?

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yes!

Comment: Make sure the content you posted elsewhere isn't under a licence that prevents you posting it here too.

Comment: sorry to step on your parade exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835183/comparing-two-guids-for-equality-in-c

Answer (score 23):

I would say the answer isn't black and white and is going to depend on a few things.

### Is it a duplicate on Stack Overflow?

The first and most important factor in whether or not you should try to do this is "has this question been asked before?".  Don't reask a question just because you want to have a self answered question.  Most likely this is only going to bring negative attention to your question.

If the question has been asked before, **and** your answer is different than all of the existing answers, then you should just answer the existing question.  Don't add your answer if you are just duplicating existing answers.  Again, this will generally only bring negative attention to your answer.

I cannot stress this enough.  Check 20 different times with as many keywords as you can think of to make sure it isn't already on Stack Overflow.  And then check some more.  Do as much (or more) research as would be expected of any new question.

### Has this been duplicated ad nauseam on the web?

As much as Stack Overflow is wants to be a centralized repository of good programming questions and answers, if something is sufficiently covered in numerous other places on web and/or covered well in official documentation, adding it to Stack Overflow seems redundant and potentially would draw traffic away from a much better resource for the problem.  If your previous answer is on a very popular resource for programmers and is easily found on the web, it seems unnecessary to duplicate it here.

### Is the answer common knowledge

This one is related to the above since it will generally be asked and answered sufficiently.

Don't ask and answer a "simple" question (one that is generally common knowledge) just for the sake of putting on Stack Overflow.  First of all, it is most likely a duplicate (unless it is an absolutely brand new language or library), but it also clutters up the feed and the search for users who have actual problems and need to find solutions in those tags.

---

Now let's say you did all of that and find a unique question that hasn't been asked before on Stack Overflow or anywhere else (except the 1 place you want to copy it from), and you decide to ask your question.  Do yourself a favor and write a good question - don't just ask "How do I...." and then go into an answer.

Self answered questions are **not** exempt from the question quality expectations.  Do your research.  Write a good question, complete with a MCVE, if applicable.  And then answer the question as asked.

Further reading on writing good self-answered questions:
[Are there guidelines to how much "What have you tried" should be in a self answered question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309576/are-there-guidelines-to-how-much-what-have-you-tried-should-be-in-a-self-answe)
[How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d)

Comment: Just a point regarding "duplicated ad nauseam on the web" - if I see SO in the search results, that's the one I'll try first.

Comment: @Kieran I try to as well, but in general, duplicating material that is sufficiently covered in dozens and dozens of other places seems completely unnecessary, especially when those places are ranked high in google.

Comment: You could always just leave a comment linking to some of the best answers already on the web

Comment: @psubsee2003 Your restraint in not mentioning Stack Overflow Documentation is commendable.

Comment: Non-original content tends to hurt SEO ranking.

Comment: I think if you have permission to reproduce the content then yes you should. SO should focus on quality content, whether it might be found somewhere else on the web.

Comment: Awhile I agree with your reasoning it doesn't match what the community has voted for. Common knowledge and duplicated ad nauseam on the web questions are some of the highest rated q&a on SO. Several of the [highest rated questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) had answers all over the web long before SO even existed. Clearly common knowledge and duplicated ad nauseam are *not* a criteria for duplicating those things on SO.

Answer (score 6):

Answering you own question is encouraged. Who answers a question is irrelevant. What matters is the value the question/answer brings to the community.

It doesn't even matter if you post a question to which you already know the answer. I've certainly done that more than once.

It doesn't matter if you answered on another site (as long as you have the rights to re-post it here). If you do so, you could add note containing a link to the original post, mentioning it's also you there so that you aren't accused of plagiarism.

So check if the question you want to post is **not a duplicate**, evaluate if the question is **on-topic**, write and format it well and by all means **go for it**!

Unfortunately, on this specific question there is an exact duplicate here: [Comparing two GUIDs for equality in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835183/comparing-two-guids-for-equality-in-c) The accepted answer here is basically a sum-up of your external answer.