# Content attribution in the era of Doc.SO's erasure

Tags: support, documentation, attribution, licensing, creative-commons

All user-provided content on SO is given under the terms of the CC-by-SA Creative Commons license. Among other things, this allows copying, but only so long as you provide attribution to the original.

Under normal circumstances, [attribution is easy enough to handle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253622/734069): a text blurb and a link to the source of the SO content. Even if the post is deleted, it is still visible to 20K rep-users, and thus attribution still qualifies. We only truly delete content rarely.

Which brings us to the end of Docs.SO. [It is going away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation). Outside of an archive, Docs.SO will be gone. And I'm not sure if it will be easy to link to a particular example in an archive.

So if you want to attribute content from Docs.SO, how exactly do you do it? Is a link to the Docs.SO archive sufficient, or does it have to be a link to something within it?

Comment: This is a good question that has been bugging me all week long. I suspect a link to the archive meets the standards of the license, but it sure seems unfriendly to contributors. When the Documentation team meets on Monday, I'll see if we can offer a better option.

Comment: Are you asking what URI to use, or are you asking about the complete attribution requirement (which the answer you linked does *not* cover from a legal standpoint, just the point of view of what some people *want* it to be, which is not what the requirement for attribution actually *is* under CC BY-SA 3.0)? (see [section 4c of the CC BY SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)) and the [Stack Exchange Terms of Service section 3 (portion about attribution)](https://stackexchange.com/legal#attribution).

Comment: If you're asking about *just the URI*, then it's: "(iii) to the extent reasonably practicable, the URI, if any, that Licensor specifies to be associated with the Work, unless such URI does not refer to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work;" (see [section 4c(iii)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)), which basically means whichever URI Stack Exchange (or the authors) say is "associated with the Work". IANAL, but IMO, it defaults to the Docs.SO JSON archive mentioned in the Sunsetting post, or none if that doesn't ref the license or copyright notice.

Answer (score 7):

Just like when SE sites get closed. See for example on Meta SE: [*What is the correct attribution for remixing content of answers.onstartups.com?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256241/193139).

**The following is what [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) requires** (based on my reading as legal layperson).

You only have to provide the URI in your attribution if it

> […] refer[s] to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work

If the page no longer contains this information (e.g., because it’s 404/410), you may omit the URI.

Relevant is the URI which the *Licensor* (which is not necessarily the *Original Author*) associates with the work. This is *not* necessarily the URI of the page where you found the work.

#### If you get the work from stackoverflow.com/documentation

… (or from someone who got it from there, and so on) and some time later stackoverflow.com/documentation is gone, then you may omit the URI in your attribution.

#### If you get the work from another source

… then you have to check their attribution for the work. Does the specified URI lead to a page that contains the necessary information ("copyright notice or licensing information")?

- If yes (which means a *Licensor* associated a new URI with the work at some point), then you have to include this URI in your attribution.
- If not (e.g., because it’s a URI from stackoverflow.com/documentation), then you may omit the URI in your attribution.
- If no attribution is provided (and the license is not violated), then a *Licensor* must have posted it there (or must have allowed to get it posted there etc.), so the associated URI is relevant.

Comment: This is just poor advice. This kind of advice assumes a URL never changes (e.g. I could not include the URL if two questions are merged because technically the information is no longer at the original URL where I got it). If a new URL where the information is accessible (like a data dump location) is available, it's still reasonable to assume that access location be included as the source, not just omitted completely.

Comment: @animuson: (I edited my answer to include the case where someone doesn’t get the work from the original place.) -- In the merge case: You *could* include the original/old URL in your attribution, but you don’t *have* to (unless it redirects to the new place, I guess)
. -- When attributing, it’s not about giving the URI where they found the work, but about giving the URI the *Licensor* associated with the work. --- On top of that it would of course be polite to point out where you found something, but the license doesn’t care about this.