# How to "save" my Documentation posts after sunset?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Since August 8, 2017, as you all know, [Documentation got sunsetted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation?cb=1).

That was pretty sad because in there were some incredible posts and examples of real programming life problems. Some of those problems keep reoccurring (or haven't been formally answered) on SO, which means that are not trivial and that adds value to the aforementioned posts.

I tried to save my posts following the suggestion of [**@TomZam**'s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/354302#354302) and composed some Q&A style posts to save my Documentation posts.

This is the format I ended with:

1. **Question:**

   - Some links (2-3) to the reoccurring problem, which my post attempts to solve.
   - An explanation on why am I doing this.
   - The actual question (trying to distill the essence of the linked questions).
2. **Answer:**

   My Documentation post saved here.

*(Example for reference: [How to execute a GROUP BY ... COUNT or SUM in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547674/how-to-execute-a-group-by-count-or-sum-in-django-orm))*

---

I do believe that this format achieves the following:

- Proves the relevance of this particular example by linking questions which can be answered by it.
- Distills the problem which led to the composition of the Documentation post.
- Saves your work.
- Can be linked to questions as one would do with a Documentation post.

---

**Points of discussion:**

- Do you believe this is a good format?
- Do you have any suggestions on changing/improving?
- Could this be a viable solution to port the best from Documentation into SO?
- Who should take the responsibility to port an example if there were multiple authors involved?

Comment: Your proposed format looks pretty good to me! We're going to have more information soon about how to correctly provide attribution. For the basic principles see the Attribution section on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355115/1438) and my answer to [Saving “Sunsetted Documentation” by creating self-answered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354481/saving-sunsetted-documentation-by-creating-self-answered-questions/354506#354506).