# Removed documentation made answers senseless

Tags: discussion, documentation

I actively contributed to the documentation and made references from various answers for the sake of reusability to point to the articles in the documentation section.

Repeating the code in the answers was, in my opinion, going against the documentation, so I am pretty sure this was right by not doing so.

However, since the documentation removal some answers cannot point to it anymore https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953352/1990451, or more exactly see the last edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41953352/revisions. I understand that the documentation did not go well and was shut down; however this particular answer became absolutely useless without the code.

What's really awful I cannot find a way to go to these documentation articles and copy the content to the answer anymore.

Should there be a possibility to at least see the documentation?

Comment: It's been archived: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links.

Comment: There was also a period during which Documentation was read-only and link-cleanup enacted to try and catch all Documentation links and edit the relevant information into those posts. Looks like a few got missed.

Comment: If the answer is senseless without the backing of the linked documentation, then it's tantamount to a link-only answer and should be edited to add the relevant information, or removed.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that I believe worked well for me is to create [self-answered posts on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354481/saving-sunsetted-documentation-by-creating-self-answered-questions) (you can even use [my suggested "template"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355866/how-to-save-my-documentation-posts-after-sunset) for those), to save the relevant material.

Then proceed to change the documentation links with the above-mentioned posts.