# Is asking for how to rename a file a bad question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I've [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but couldn't find a reason why my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722419/how-can-i-rename-a-swift-playground-file  is a bad question.

I'm not asking for a tool. Rather asking how to work with a tool provided to developers. I searched online and didn't find anything which answers my question and believe me I've asked iOS folks before and they didn't know. The solution is a bit counter-intuitive.

I also looked under the section of *Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above* and didn't find anything.

I wanted to delete, but since I didn't find a reason for it, I thought I should ask here first.

**EDIT:**

If you're an iOS developer you're more likely to appreciate the question. I looked into the duplicate question. I did Google. I did look into the documentation. I did ask other folks. What else am I suppose to do? I have been coding with playground for about 2 years now. Only after 2 years I found this solution. Call me dumb or whatever, <s>but the solution was counter intuitive knowing you can change the name in Xcode, but can't do it in playground.</s>

**EDIT2**

I deleted the question because it was low quality. You can change the name in Xcode, but neither Xcode or Playground offer rename upon right click. You just have hit enter on the file (from within the IDE) or just do `show in Finder`.

I guess I was having a bad day. **No need to reopen this**. Perhaps I should delete this meta post...

Comment: It's not something unique to software development... how could renaming a specific file could be so abstract of what you would expect of renaming any other file?

Comment: What do you mean it's not unique to software development? I'm not talking about spaghetti. I'm talking about an IDE. I use playgrounds to do quick code. And like to keep the files organized. The documentation doesn't provide a solution.  Didn't understand your 2nd sentence. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: The question is about how to use a programming IDE. Seems legit to me. I suspect that it was downvoted by people that did not uderstand that. Screenshots would probably have helped.

Comment: The question is a bit low on context which might put people off. They expect with swift in the title and xcode in the tags the question to be about programming I guess but it isn't immediately clear you're talking about some IDE.

Comment: @rene how should I edit the question to make it likable? Can you make an edit/

Comment: I'm not an Apple dev, I've sold my soul to M$. I'm of no use here ...

Comment: @rene I added an image.

Comment: @Honey simply stating something to the effect of "From within the IDE how do I..." would have made it clear enough I would think.

Comment: @EBGreen ok. Done!

Comment: Almost ironic, but I'm new and wondering why this meta question is considered bad by so many. If @Honey had added ""From within the IDE" to this question would it have been acceptable?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic what's more interesting is **nothing** from the 'What topics can I ask about here' has anything against my question. Yet I've received 5 downvotes on the original question and one on the answer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic The Meta downvotes don't make much sense. By and large, I don't think we should downvote good faith attempts to understand why a question has been poorly received.

Comment: Funny that provided answer *does not* use IDE at all... "I tried to rename file in Finder ... " could have been part of research in the question - does not sound like IDE operation at all.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov by that logic and some exaggeration **any** answer could potentially be part of the research of an OP. Obviously that's wrong. It may or may not just signify it's a newbie question. My point was... it's just counter intuitive. Because in Xcode itself, you can rename files directly. In playgrounds, you can't! Which is bad design. The question is about the bad design. The answer is how to address it

Comment: Your answer does not answer your question "From within the IDE..." (unlike "in Xcode itself, you can rename files directly. In playgrounds, you can't!" comment)... Unfortunately this is common for self-answered questions - answer whatever authors *wanted to ask* and not what the question actually asks. Self-answered questions are hard - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309576/are-there-guidelines-to-how-much-what-have-you-tried-should-be-in-a-self-answe and duplicates have discussions about what should/should not be in question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you're taking things literally. I'm trying to get the job done. But I'll make an edit

Comment: I think that in its current form it's definitely not a bad question. At first it was unclear that you were talking about the IDE. If some other people having the same problem come across the Q&A and find it useful they will upvote it. Or at least the answer...

Comment: *"what's more interesting is nothing from the 'What topics can I ask about here' has anything against my question"* - that page lists reasons to **close** a question. Up/downvoting is based on content quality. If a question gets downvoted, people don't find the question good quality/useful. That can easily be true for questions (or answers) which are otherwise on-topic.

Comment: @Gimby you're not an iOS developer, so you wouldn't know.

Comment: @Honey a strange response, I'm just stating the reason to downvote something. If the question is about iOS is irrelevant, it is the same workflow for any and all questions on the site.

Comment: @Gimby it's relevant. Most folks here with the counter argument don't have iOS experience. hence not aware of its hassle

Comment: I can't see the question, but from the discussion here it seems to have been a fair one. "How can I rename a file from a specific IDE", with the self-answer "You can't, you have to use the Finder instead". Sounds like it would be useful to future visitors.

Comment: @Honey: You can consider Gimby as an SO expert. He just told you that being on-topic doesn't mean that a question is high quality. Voting is about quality, closing is about on-topic/off-topic. He never said anything about the quality of your question, just states a fact about SO die which you really don't have to be an expert in iOS.

Comment: @BDL you're right. I misjudged because my question was initially closed and this meta post was downvoted vigorously.